# Focus lost with jAlert plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling jAlert with this function

```
$('.stcommentdelete').live("click",function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var dataString = 'com_id='+ ID;

    jConfirm('Oled sa kindel, et tahad kustutada??', '', function(r){
        if(r==true){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete_comment_ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#stcommentbody"+ID).slideUp();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

If i have for example 15 comments and i would delete last comment, it scrolls up. But i need that it stays focused on this place where i delete comment.

Omerimuni

Comment: An idea is using the .focus() function, after the confirm box. So $(this).focus() will may be help.

Comment: i have tried allready your idea. Yes it focus, but after jAlert confirmbox is closed. So i need something else.

Comment: To prevent a misunderstanding, I meant follows: jConfirm(){} and then $(this).focus(). Not within jConfirm(){}

Comment: Nope. its still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong in my script. I called this script from link like a href="#". I remove href="#" and it works. :D Sry for bother u guys ;)